# Getting error of “Can't find variable: _fbBatchedBridge” while running react-native run-android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I created a new React-Native project.
Then I run the following commands:

- react-native start
- react-native run-android

While running these commands, I successfully installed the app in android phone (Xiaomi redmi note 3).But I am getting  this following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
java.lang.RuntimeException: ReferenceError:
Can't find variable: _fbBatchedBridge
```

Comment: take a look at this link : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4881 . It's the same issue.

Comment: Thanks. I got answer => Shake your device or hit the menu and go to Dev Settings, Debug Server host and port, seek for the host and port of your computer, and put them there... eg. 192.168.1.4:8081 in my case, then shake again and click reload JS, all it's set up :)